# default value for functions in parameters in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, default-parameters

I was learning and experimenting with Scala. I wanted to implement a function with generic type, which takes a function as a parameter and provides a default implementation of that function..

Now when I try it without the generic type, it works :

```
def defaultParamFunc(z: Int, y: Int)(f: (Int, Int) => Int = (v1: Int,v2: Int) => { v1 + v2 }) : Int = {
  val ans = f(z,y)
  println("ans : " + ans)
  ans
}
```

this doesn't give any error

but when I try the same with generic type,

```
def defaultParamFunc[B](z: B, y: B)(f: (B, B) => B = (v1: B,v2: B) => { v1 + v2 }) = {
  val ans = f(z,y)
  println("ans : " + ans)
  ans
}
```

I get the error :

```
[error]  found   : B
[error]  required: String
[error]  def defaultParamFunc[B](z: B, y: B)(f: (B, B) => B = (v1: B,v2: B) => { v1 + v2 }) = {
[error]                                                                               ^
```

Is the error because the compiler doesn't know if B type will be addable ? because when I just return v1 or v2 instead of v1 + v2, it works..

```
def defaultParamFunc[B](z: B, y: B)(f: (B, B) => B = (v1: B,v2: B) => { v1 }) = {
  val ans = f(z,y)
  println("ans : " + ans)
  ans
}
```

If so, How to specify that the type given must be Numeric ? I tried replacing B with B : Numeric but still gives the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem with your code is a minor omission: you need to import the members of the `Numeric` instance, so as to bring `+` into scope (this will in fact bring `num.mkNumericOps` into scope, enabling the `+` method):
Let's try this:

```
def defaultParamFunc[B](z: B, y: B)(f: (B, B) => B = (v1: B,v2: B) => { v1 + v2 })(implicit num: Numeric[B]) = {
  // Brings `+` into scope.
  // Note that you can also just import Numeric.Implicits._ for the same effect
  import num._

  val ans = f(z,y)
  println("ans : " + ans)
  ans
}
```

Unfortunately this still does not compile. The problem here is that a parameter's default value can only reference a parameter from an earlier parameter list.
Because `num` is in the last parameter list, there is no way to use it in a default value.
Tough luck.

OK, so let's try to outsmart the compiler and split the method in two, so that we can have the implicit parameter `num` before the parameter `f`:

```
def defaultParamFunc[B](z: B, y: B)(implicit num: Numeric[B]) = new {
  // NOTE: using structural typing here is rather inefficient.
  //       Let's ignore that for now.
  import num._
  def apply(f: (B, B) => B = (v1: B, v2: B) => { v1 + v2 }) = {
    val ans = f(z,y)
    println("ans : " + ans)
    ans
  }
}
```

Sweet, it compiles. What we have done here is that `defaultParamFunc` actually returns a (pseudo) function instance. This function is what takes `f` as parameter, 
and because we instantiate the function in `defaultParamFunc` body there is no problem referencing `num`.

However, let's not rejoice too soon. If we try to call it, without specifying the `f` parameter, the compiler is not happy:

```
scala> defaultParamFunc(5, 7)()
<console>:17: error: not enough arguments for method defaultParamFunc: (implicit num: Numeric[Int])((Int, Int) => Int) => Int{def apply$default$1: (Int, Int) => Int}.
Unspecified value parameter num.
          defaultParamFunc(5, 7)()
```

Oops. The compiler thinks that the empty parameter list is for the second (implicit) parameter list in `defaultParamFunc`, rather than in the parameter list of  the (pseudo) function instance.

We'll have to find another way that does not require an implicit parameter in the `defaultParamFunc` method. [Magnet patterns](http://spray.io/blog/2012-12-13-the-magnet-pattern/) to the rescue!

```
trait MyMagnet[B] extends ((B,B) => B)
object MyMagnet {
  implicit def fromFunc[B]( f: (B, B) => B ) = new MyMagnet[B] {
    def apply(z: B, y: B): B = {
      val ans = f(z,y)
      println("ans : " + ans)
      ans
    }
  }
  implicit def fromUnit[B](unit: Unit)(implicit num: Numeric[B]) = new MyMagnet[B]{
    import num._
    def apply(v1: B, v2: B): B = { v1 + v2 }
  }
}
def defaultParamFunc[B](z: B, y: B)(magnet: MyMagnet[B]): B = magnet(z, y)
```

Granted, this is a bit contrived for such a tiny result. But it does work:

```
scala> defaultParamFunc(2,3)()
res15: Int = 5

scala> defaultParamFunc(2,3){(x:Int, y:Int) => x*y }
ans : 6
res16: Int = 6
```

Note though that by using the magnet pattern, we have lost the benefits of type inference. So we cannot just do the following:

```
scala> defaultParamFunc(2,3)(_ * _)
<console>:18: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1, x$2) => x$1.$times(x$2))
              defaultParamFunc(2,3)(_ * _)
```

Comment: ok. I tried your code. It's not compiling. When I use defaultParamFunc(2,3)() It gives the error 'Unspecified value parameter magnet'. when I tried defaultParamFunc(2,3){(x:Int, y:Int) => x*y }, I got the error 'found   : (Int, Int) => Int
required: test.ScalaTest.MyMagnet[Int]
Note: implicit method fromUnit is not applicable here because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type'

Comment: Well it **does** compile (tested in the REPL, scala version 2.10.1). In the REPL you just have to take care to evaluate the `MyMagnet` *trait* and the `MyMagnet` *object* together, otherwise the latter won't be seen as the companion object of the former. However I can see from the error message that you are not using the REPL. All I can suggest is that you post the exact code (as in "the whole source file(s)") so I can see what is wrong.

Comment: Sorry. I am new to scala. I am not using REPL. I am running it using SBT. My scala version is 2.10.3. Here is the file : http://pastebin.com/HDgprLZD

Comment: OK.. now it's working.. silly mistake.. Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. It was very informative. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is the error because the compiler doesn't know if B type will be addable ?

Yes. The type parameter `B` has no constraints in your example - you could use any type as the argument when you use this function. The compiler has no way to check in advance that whatever type you use has a `+` method.

You can use a type class approach, here's something to give you an idea:

```
// This defines a generic 'plus' method
trait Plus[T] {
  def plus(x: T, y: T): T
}

// This is a generic method that can do 'plus' on whatever type
// for which there is an implicit Plus value in scope
def add[T : Plus](a: T, b: T) = implicitly[Plus[T]].plus(a, b)

// This defines what 'plus' means for Ints
implicit val intPlus = new Plus[Int] {
  def plus(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x + y
}

// This defines what 'plus' means for Strings
implicit val stringPlus = new Plus[String] {
  def plus(x: String, y: String): String = x.concat(y)
}

// Examples of use
println(add(2, 3))
println(add("hello", "world"))
```

*edit*: Actually, Scala's `Numeric` already does this for you:

```
def add[T : Numeric](x: T, y: T) = implicitly[Numeric[T]].plus(x, y)

// Use it with integers
println(add(2, 3))

// Or doubles
println(add(1.5, 2.4))

// Or with for example BigDecimal
println(add(BigDecimal("1.234"), BigDecimal("4.567")))
```

So you should be able to do something like this:

```
def defaultParamFunc[B : Numeric](z: B, y: B)(f: (B, B) => B = (v1: B,v2: B) => { implicitly[Numeric[B]].plus(v1, v2) }) = {
  val ans = f(z,y)
  println("ans : " + ans)
  ans
}
```

Comment: This does not compile (please see my answer)

Comment: Thanks for your response. The first example worked but using the numeric code, I got the error 
'could not find implicit value for parameter e: Numeric[B]' in the defaultParamFunc function. the add function worked